# Hide an element when a user clicks outside of it

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$( document ).on('click', '.toggle_comments', function( event ){

    event.preventDefault();

    var container = $('div[name="comments"]');

    if ( container.css('display') == 'block' ) {

        container.hide();

        return;
    }

    container.fadeIn(500);
});
```

When `.toggle_comments` is clicked, the container fades in. Is there a way to do something, ie fadeout, if anything outside the container is clicked WHILE it's display block? Bearing in mind, obviously, that `.toggle_comments` is outside of it in the first place. So it needs to be a live event, something that only fires while the container is in the state if `display:block`.

Comment: Can you put your requirement precisely?

Comment: Try using js targets

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can bind a `mousedown` event to `document` and check if the element clicked on is not `div[name="comments"]` like so:

```
$(document).mousedown(function(event)
{
    var commentSection = $('div[name="comments"]');

    if(!$(commentSection).is($(event.target)) && !$(event.target).closest($(commentSection)).length)
        $(commentSection).fadeOut();
});
```

Comment: I want the container to fadeout if anything else but the comment container is clicked. This fades out if the container is clicked too.

Comment: ie. If comment section is block and it's clicked on, it doesn't fadeout, but if anything outside of it is clicked, it fades out.

Comment: Just added that to my answer for you

Comment: The problem with this is that if anything INSIDE the container is clicked, it also fades it out, so it's right in principle. See my fiddle. Click the red background and it works fine, but click the paragraphs inside and it fades out. https://jsfiddle.net/4cuuhtyq/

Comment: Ah I understand you now, let me modify my answer

Comment: There we go, took longer than it should've but there's your intended functionality ;)

Comment: Now it doesn't fade out when outside of it is clicked :P

Comment: Strange...let me see what's going on here. Works on the fiddle but not my dev site.

Comment: No errors and the click function is firing if I put `alert ('happened');` after `$(commentSection).fadeOut();`

Comment: What if you add the alert inside the if statement?

Comment: `if(!$(commentSection).is(event.target) && !$(event.target).parents(commentSection).length && alert ('happened'))` = no alert.

Comment: Strange, `parents` wasn't returning the expected value. Try the code I've just updated my post with

Comment: That works! Few other problems I have to sort, but for the purpose of this question that's correct. Thanks!

Comment: One more thing! How can I also do something like this? `$(document).mousedown(function(event)
{
    var commentSection = $('div[name="comments"]');

    if(!$(commentSection).is($(event.target)) && !$(event.target).closest($(commentSection)).length)

        $(commentSection).hide();
        $(".the-content p .inline-comments-highlight-text").contents().unwrap();



});
`
the .unwrap(); happens even clicking inside the container?

Answer (score 2):

Just do different things if different elements are clicked

```
$( document ).on('click', function( event ){
    event.preventDefault();

    var target    = $(event.target);
    var container = $('div[name="comments"]');

    if ( target.closest('.toggle_comments').length > 0 ) {
        if ( container.is(':visible') ) {
            container.hide();
        } else {
            container.fadeIn(500);
        }
    } else if (target.closest(container).length === 0 && container.is(':visible')) {
        container.fadeOut(500); 
    } 
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/wb7psdyn/1/)

Comment: But then the original function doesn't work, ie. clicking on toggle_comments no longer toggles them. For various reasons they need to be separate.

Comment: Why wouldn't the toggle work, did you try the Fiddle, I encorporated that into the same function ?